# TileMill : Assigning band combination

Tags: raster, tilemill

I am working on Tile Mill Version 0.10.1 (v0.10.1) on windows 7. I have satellite image of world view 2. I am converting that image to .mbtiles.

My problem is I am unable to assign any band combination in above software.

I researched and going though [this similar](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/landsat-8-imagery/) article but unable to get bands in image (it has 4 bands and output format is 'tif')

Please refer screenshots  [image: band combinations]